# Solving weights in least squares to reduce distance to another vector

Tags: optimization, least-squares, linear-algebra, generalized-least-squares

I'm using a procedure of WLS to find some values in a reduced space that actually generate a vector that is close to my target vector. That is, I have WLS:

$\beta=(X^T W X)^{-1} X^T W Y$, and I am trying to find the optimal W to minimize the difference of these values, $X \beta$, to some other vector $Z$ (in same space as $Y$, but not related): 
$W^* = \text{argmin}_W (\text{error}(X \beta, Z))$
Where the error function is a distance measure--perhaps an L2 norm for simplicity.
I feel like this is perhaps an unconventional twist on a very conventional problem and am looking for any guidance on how to tackle it efficiently.

Comment: If you care about minimizing the L2 distance from $X\beta$ to $Z$, why not just use OLS as follows:  $\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ$? ...or letters to that effect, since you wouldn't implement the calculation that way.

Comment: The original regression of Y onto X projects down from a high dimensional space (e.g. 100s-1000) to a low one (e.g. 5-25). The output beta is then in that reduced space (also a function of the W matrix, whose rank is the dim of the big space, and is the matrix I'm trying to optimize). If I premultiply by X, I can get Y hat--my nearest values given those weights. If I understand correctly, what you described will get me vector in the small space that I'd want to be nearest to, but it's not clear how that gets at the optimal weights of the original problem.

Comment: Right, but why do you care about $W$ in the first place?  You have $X$ and $Z$, and there doesn't seem to be any reason why you actually need the original $W$ and $\beta$ as calculated in the question.  (I'm sure you have a reason, it's just that it's not at all clear what it is.)

Comment: In my case, I am tied to the WLS implementation (out of my control). However, it might be easier to think about in a predictive sense, even though this is not exactly my use case. For example, Y represents the live data (in 'big' space), Y_hat is my best live, low dimensional estimate of that live data, and Z is some future value of the Y.